# MySql How to minimum value one row

Tags: mysql

I will send an email to my client when approaching the measurement date with php. Something measurement valid one year, something valid 3 years, etc... therefore one company's data one row. But I would like write, that how many days valid his measurement.
I hope yours understand my problem. Thanks in advance! Adam

I have a table with structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `meresek` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `COMP_ID` varchar(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'What a company ID',

  `Comp_V` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'What size number of sites',

  `MERES_1` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MERES_END_1` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `EV_MERES_2` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MERES_END_2` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MERES_3` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MERES_END_3` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MERES_4` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `MERES_END_4` date DEFAULT NULL,
  .
  .
  .
  .
  `MERES_END_8` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `COMP_ID` (`COMP_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=70;


INSERT INTO `meresek` ( `ID`, `COMP_ID`, `COMP_V`,`MERES_1`
  `MERES_END_1`,
  `EV_MERES_2`,
  `MERES_END_2`,
  `MERES_3`,
  `MERES_END_3`,
   .
   .
   .
   `MERES_END_8) VALUES


(1, 'X1', 1, NULL, NULL, '2011-03-07', '2011-03-31', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),

(2, 'X2', 1, NULL, NULL, '2010-12-19', '2019-12-31', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),

(3, 'Y11', 1, NULL, NULL, '2011-05-12', '2014-12-31', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-05-12', '2020-05-12', '2011-05-12', '2020-05-12', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),

(4, 'Y12', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2012-02-02', '2013-02-02', '2012-02-02', '2013-02-02')
```

Comment: If English is not a language in which you're particularly adept, consider taking advantage of Google's translation tools, because right now you're not making a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Dear Strawberry I first translated with google. But I try repeat. I have this structure (upside). I will change the least value from one row. And this value I will send an email. How to change least value one row? Thanks and sorry. Adam.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you have to back to the drawing board with this one. Any time you see 'xxx1,xxx2,xxx3' it's a sure sign that the design is in desperate need of normalization.

Answer (score 0):

select least(
coalesce(`col_1,col_2....col_8`),
coalesce(`col_2,col_1....col_8`),
coalesce(`col_3,col_1....col_8`),
coalesce(`col_4,col_1....col_8`),
coalesce(`col_5,col_1....col_8`),
coalesce(`col_6,col_1....col_8`),
coalesce(`col_7,col_1....col_8`),
coalesce(`col_8,col_1....col_1`)) where id = '35'